# Unable to locate excel enumerations typelib in win 7 registry

Tags: windows, com, tcl

I used the following code to try to get reference for Excel enumerations Typelib.
But it returned the error shown below:

```
(>) 11 % set application Excel.Application
Excel.Application
(>) 12 % set clsID [registry get HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\$application\\CLSID {}]
{00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
(>) 13 % set typeLib [registry get         HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\$application\\CLSID\\$clsID\\Typelib {}]
unable to open key: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Is it required to install the typelib or some component.

Also looked up for all applications in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT that had Excel in their names and also had a clsId and typeLib reference. Following are the applications that I found but I am not sure which one to choose:

```
     Excel.Addin
     Excel.AddInMacroEnabled
     Excel.Backup
     Excel.Chart
     Excel.Chart.8
     Excel.CSV
     Excel.Dialog
     Excel.Macrosheet
     Excel.OpenDocumentSpreadsheet
     Excel.OpenDocumentSpreadsheet.12
     Excel.Sheet
     Excel.Sheet.12
     Excel.Sheet.8
     Excel.SheetBinaryMacroEnabled
     Excel.SheetBinaryMacroEnabled.12
     Excel.SheetMacroEnabled
     Excel.SheetMacroEnabled.12
     Excel.SLK
     Excel.Template
     Excel.Template.8
     Excel.TemplateMacroEnabled
     Excel.Workspace
     Excel.XLL
     WbxMSAI.WebExExcelAddin
     WbxMSAI.WebExExcelAddin.1
     Excel.Addin
     Excel.AddInMacroEnabled
     Excel.Backup
     Excel.Chart
     Excel.Chart.8
     Excel.CSV
     Excel.Dialog
     Excel.Macrosheet
     Excel.OpenDocumentSpreadsheet
     Excel.OpenDocumentSpreadsheet.12
     Excel.Sheet
     Excel.Sheet.12
     Excel.Sheet.8
     Excel.SheetBinaryMacroEnabled
     Excel.SheetBinaryMacroEnabled.12
     Excel.SheetMacroEnabled
     Excel.SheetMacroEnabled.12
     Excel.SLK
     Excel.Template
     Excel.Template.8
     Excel.TemplateMacroEnabled
     Excel.Workspace
     Excel.XLL
     WbxMSAI.WebExExcelAddin
     WbxMSAI.WebExExcelAddin.1
     Excel.Addin
     Excel.AddInMacroEnabled
     Excel.Backup
     Excel.Chart
     Excel.Chart.8
     Excel.CSV
     Excel.Dialog
     Excel.Macrosheet
     Excel.OpenDocumentSpreadsheet
     Excel.OpenDocumentSpreadsheet.12
     Excel.Sheet
     Excel.Sheet.12
     Excel.Sheet.8
     Excel.SheetBinaryMacroEnabled
     Excel.SheetBinaryMacroEnabled.12
     Excel.SheetMacroEnabled
     Excel.SheetMacroEnabled.12
     Excel.SLK
     Excel.Template
     Excel.Template.8
     Excel.TemplateMacroEnabled
     Excel.Workspace
     Excel.XLL
     WbxMSAI.WebExExcelAddin
     WbxMSAI.WebExExcelAddin.1
```

Comment: You are just reading the wrong key.  Use Regedit.exe to see this for yourself.  I don't know TCL but if I interpret it correctly then you need to use HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\CLSID\\$clsID\\Typelib {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the key Excel.Sheet to get a CLSID with the function CLSIDFromString in ole32.dll (which I think that just looks in the Classes of the Registry).

Then look for  'CLSID\' clsid '\TypeLib' in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT like you did, to get the GUID of the lib.

Finally, we use the LoadRegTypeLib with that GUID (and the version numbers, which are also in the registry) to get the handle for an ITypeLib.